# Will merging a Git branch with deletions also delete files in master?

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

I use Git for my project version controlling. Now I'm working on a minor feature that doesn't depend much on the code base. So in order to develop the feature, I created a new branch based on the master branch and deleted from the new branch most of the code that was not related to the new feature(so that the compiled jar file is relatively small and easy for distribution).

Now I need to merge the branch back to the master branch. My concern is, will the deletions in the new branch be reflected in the merged result? I only want the modifications and additions (but not deletions) in the new branch to be reflected in the merged result. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete files from your branch and not have those deletions also reflected in the `master` branch when your feature branch is merged into it.

Also, in the future, you could always just do the merge locally and see the result. If you don't like it, you could always undo the merge locally and reset `master` to where it was before by using one of the following:

```
$ git reset --hard head~
$ git reset --hard head^
$ git reset --hard head@{1}
$ git reset --hard master@{1}
$ git reset --hard <sha of previous commit of master>
```

The first 4 commands are shorthand (in this case) for the last one.